# Matlab break X axis

Tags: matlab

I am having a trouble in showing a plot which runs from **0-10K**.
Currently I have calculation running from 0-100 and it looks great.

Currently:

[image]

Now I want to add one X points which is **10K**
And it looks this way:
[image]

How do I keep it from 0-100 and show only then the jumps to **10K** ? 
Is it even possible ?

The problem is that 0-100 is very small portion in `10K` so it looks bad.

Comment: You don't want to break the x-axis - you want it to be logarithmic: semilogx. - This would be the proper scientific way to display your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could plot your one outlier point at a closer x coordinate, then adjust the [`XTick`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_d0e51413) and [`XTickLabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_d0e51535) properties to make it appear as though there is a break in the plot range. For example:

```
plot([1:20 25], 1./[1:20 10000]);
set(gca, 'XTick', [2:2:20 25], ...
         'XTickLabel', strtrim(cellstr(int2str([2:2:20 10000].'))));
```

And here's the plot this creates:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to sample the x points (for the second plot) in different gaps. You can combine two arrays of x sample points (each array with a fixed gap but the first gap is much smaller than the second gap). then you plot the combined points.

Here's a code example:

```
clear;
close all;
clc;

gap1 = 0.2;
x_left = 1:gap1:3;
gap2 = 0.5;
x_right = 3+gap2:gap2:6;
x_ticks_for_plot = [x_left x_right];

x=x_ticks_for_plot;
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y);
xticks(x_ticks_for_plot);
```

And the plot:

[image]

In your case the second gap should be much bigger than the first but it's the same idea.